# Unable to run Dev Express Form in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008, devexpress

I created a form name 'AddProject' using DevExpress in a new project.
If I build the solution, I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'AddProject' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I also tried to add it in Program.cs as:

```
Application.Run(new AddProject());
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question and post the line of code and/or location where the error occurs.

Comment: @helb I am getting error when I am trying to Add form in Program.cs

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the project containing the AddProject class is added as Reference to your application (Expand your application project in the solution explorer, right-click References, select "Projects" tab, select the AddProject project).

Also, make sure you are using the namespace in Program.cs:

```
using AddProject; // or whatever the namespace of the AddProject class is
```

Comment: There is no "AddProject" in 'Projects' tab in the 'Add Reference'.
How can I add it in my project?
I simply created a 'Forms' Folder then in that folder I add new item 'AddProject'

Comment: Ok, then `using AddProject;` should suffice.

Comment: I add 'using AddProject' in Program.cs but it could not recognize it and give me he same error.